# Why I can't refer to class variable from nested class?

Tags: python, class

In simple case I can call `teacher` in `loh` function:

```
class Student:
   teacher = 'Mrs. Jones'

   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
    
def loh():
  print(Student.teacher)

loh()

### Mrs. Jones
```

But, If I try to do that next way, I got mistake "not defined". Why?

```
class Student:
  class UnderStudent:
    teacher = 'Mrs. Jones'
  def f():
    print(UnderStudent.teacher)
  f()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: ...and notice that "inside nested classes" is **not** listed as one of the scopes searched in the accepted answer. Very little is gained from nesting classes in Python which is why it's seldom used. I do it anyway sometimes, just to indicate that nested class isn't used anywhere else (although it *is* still accessible outside the class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` tries to lookup `UnderStudent` in the global scope, but the name isn't defined there; it's only defined in the namespace of the `class` statement, which turns the name into a class attribute.

```
class Student:
    class UnderStudent:
        teacher = 'Mrs.Jones'
    def f(self):
        print(self.UnderStudent.teacher)
        # or print(Student.UnderStudent.teacher)
```

Nested classes are rare in Python, as there is no restriction on having multiple top-level classes in the same file as in some other languages.

Comment: @SharimIqbal: `f` is a method of `Student` objects; you need to create a `Student` to call `f` on first.

Comment: Because I added `self` as the missing parameter to your instance method.  Why would you want to call `f` from inside the `class` statement anyway?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it that way for the same reason you can't just say `teacher` without qualifying it with `self` or `Student` (`Student.teacher` is a class attribute of `Student` in your first example; in your second example, `Student.UnderStudent` is a class attribute of `Student` that just happens to be a class itself). `UnderStudent` doesn't exist at global scope, it only exists within the scope of `Student`, just like `teacher` did.

You also have to invoke `f` *after* `Student` is fully defined, because until you exit the scope of `Student`'s definition, `Student` doesn't exist in global scope (so you can't use it to find `UnderStudent`). To fix, you could do:

```
class Student:
  class UnderStudent:
    teacher = 'Mrs. Jones'
  def f(self):
    print(Student.UnderStudent.teacher)
    # or
    print(self.UnderStudent.teacher)

Student().f()
```

Comment: I feel like this misses an important point of *why* ``UnderStudent`` refers to the global scope and not the containing scope – like it would do if it were ``def Student...`` instead of ``class Student...``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: `UnderStudent` doesn't refer to the global scope, so I don't know what's confusing you. The problem is that, like *anything* defined inside a class, it exists within that class's scope. `UnderStudent` is an attribute of `Student`, just like any other method or class attribute of `Student` (the OP seems to understand the concept of class attributes after all; `UnderStudent` is neither more nor less than a class attribute that just happened to be defined as a nested class rather than through simple assignment).

Comment: The bare reference ``UnderStudent`` (as e.g. in the OP's ``print(UnderStudent.teacher)``) *does* refer to global scope. That's usually not how nested name resolution works, which allows accessing the containing scope in any other case. I'm not *confused* by the answer (I know how this works) but think this is an important point since people usually don't get that there are different kinds of scopes when only presented with one.